# How to activate all bundles in go in cq5

Tags: curl, aem

I need to know the curl command to start all the bundles in one go in adobe CQ5

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no OSGi console command to do that in either Apache Sling or CQ.

You might get the list of bundles via `/system/console/bundles.json` and build the appropriate requests out of that, or create a server-side servlet or script with the appropriate logic.